# Worklight 6.2 - Issue with cookies that have command and ampersand

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

It seems the server included in the studio environment doesn't like certain forms of cookies. If you have a cookie with both a command and ampersand in it, the part of the server that serves static assets starts throwing 500s (although any worklight adapter calls still work).

To repro:

Using WL studio version: 0801-1709

- Open a worklight mobile web app in chrome (e.g. `http://localhost:10080/<project>/apps/services/preview/<app>/mobilewebapp/1.0/default/MobileSite.html`)
- Open the Chrome developer console and set a cookie: `document.cookie="foobar=or,e & o"`
- Reload the page

Result:  You get the following error on all the static asset request (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.)

`Application Error 
SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'javax.servlet.http.Cookie.:139' 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cookie name "e & o" is a reserved token 
at javax.servlet.http.Cookie.(Cookie.java:139) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.request.IRequestImpl.getCookies(IRequestImpl.java:151) 
at [internal classes]`

Additional info:

- This doesn't occur on WL 6.1
- This doesn't occur on the GA level of the SERVER (I don't the ability to test the 0801 level of SERVER nor the GA level of studio)
- Error appears to be triggered by the combination of having both command and ampersand.

Please let me know if there's any more info I can provide to help track down this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This might share some light [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23715821/3456790). I think the main thing to take from this is not to have whitespace between special characters like the ampersand.